# How to Remove Three Dots in Pagination

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to this forum.
I'm trying pagination for my own demo website. When long pagination (...) three dot occurs and I don't want that. How can I remove that three dots?

See the image: [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfQNP.png)

And here my code:

```js
$(function() {
        var flexiblePagination = $('#contents').flexiblePagination({
            itemsPerPage : 4,
            displayedPages: 5,
            itemSelector : 'div.content:visible',
            pagingControlsContainer : '#pagination',
            showingInfoSelector : '#showingInfo',
            btnFirstText: "First",
            btnLastText: "Last",
            btnNextText: "Next",
            btnPreviousText: "Prev",
            css: {
                btnNumberingClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
                btnFirstClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
                btnLastClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
                btnNextClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
                btnPreviousClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-success'
            }
        });
        flexiblePagination.getController().onPageClick = function(pageNum, e){
            console.log('You Clicked Page: '+pageNum)
        };

    });
```

Comment: Yes im using FlexiblePagination

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/content-paginator-flexiblepaginationjs.html

Comment: https://filebin.net/8h6c8itlafev6vfb/Flexiblepagination.js?t=rb1f2gz2

Comment: see the plugin i upoladed that file link

Comment: have you tried this? are you getting some unexpected issues? You need to clarify the exact problem you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your displayedPages: 5 to maximum number of your pages or you will need to edit js file of plug in itself.

In your Flexible.Pagination.js file on line 324 is this line:

```
if ( starting != (numPages-1)){
            pagingControls += createButton('...', 'se-page-num'+this.instanceId+' '+this.css.btnActiveClass, true);
        }
```

try removing it, or remove just ... and see what happens.

Comment: i remove that line its removes that dot but it doesnt show the next page number its shows  the page like 1 2 3 11 12 instead of 4 & 5.

Comment: well did you try setting displayedPages: 5 to displayedPages: 12? Like i first suggested.

Comment: yes.. But i don't want that because it will show 12 page number so it will look longer and disgusting to see....i want to like (First Prev 1 2 3 4 5  Next Last ) when i click next it will move on to next page number 6

Comment: anyone help please

Comment: I tried and I don't know how to do that, And what you asking is just bad practice. You should show people how many pages are left. Try finding other plugin, panty of those out there, maybe some have this setting.